# WebM Alpha only displayed in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, webm

I've implemented a WebM video with the video tag. The alpha channel is displayed correctly in Chrome but not in Firefox nor Edge - there's a black background.

I thought those browsers had good support for WebM? Am I missing something?

Markup looks like this:

```html
<video autoplay loop muted poster="example.jpg">
  <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

Thanks in advance! :)

//EDIT
I got alpha channel working with Firefox:
Used VP8 instead of VP9 codec.
Edge is still a mystery.